# go: How to json.Marshal map[int]int?

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I know, Json does not support anything else than strings for keys.

But converting entire `map[int]int` to temporaty `map[string]int` is not always possible because second one does not fit into memory.

Is there an approach to convert int key on the fly?

Is there any json-like format with int keys? YAML? Some binary format?

Comment: To understand your problem: why do you need to marshal into portable format?

Comment: @elithrar i don't need to and don't have to. The only restriction for the format is to be backward-compartible: it must support loading old files with no new keys it the file

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't convert the map on the fly. You will need to have your original map till you populate the new one (then it can be removed).

First question you have to ask yourself: what are you going to do with that json, because modern computers have a lot of RAM, so storing even 4gb will not be a problem (and I highly doubt you are going to send 4gb json request).

Once you know why exactly are you encoding your stuff you can look for an appropriate format.

For example you can serialize your map.

<kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/QIWKQD4EL9)</kbd>

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/gob"
    "bytes"
)

var m = map[int]string{1:"one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}

func main() {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(buf)

    err := encoder.Encode(m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

// your encoded stuff
fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())

    var decodedMap map[int]string
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(buf)

    err = decoder.Decode(&decodedMap)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", decodedMap)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the encoding in code. It's easy and will probably be faster as a bonus.

This should work:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
first := true
fmt.Fprint(&buf, "{")
for k, v := range m {
    if first {
        first = false
    } else {
        fmt.Fprint(&buf, ",")
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(&buf, `"%d":%d`, k, v)
}
fmt.Fprint(&buf, "}")
```

If you need to pass this on to `encoding/json` you can use `json.RawMessage(buf.Bytes())`.

Comment: json key is only string format

Comment: @ZhasulanBerdibekov hence the quotes around the keys, `"%d"`.